# how to send long message using node smpp?

Tags: node.js, buffer, smpp, pdu, smscaster

```
exports.sendSMS = function (session, to, text, sourceAddress, jsonMessageHistoryIds, callback) {

     console.log('messege',text);

    session.submit_multi({
        source_addr: sourceAddress,
        dest_address: to,
        short_message: text

    }, function (pdu) {
        console.log('submit_multi: ', pdu.command_status);
        console.log("PDU", pdu);
        if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
            // insert into sms smpp logs
            var values = {
                type: 'bulk',
                message: text,
                numbers: JSON.stringify(to)
            };

        console.log(pdu.message_id);
            callback(null, pdu.message_id);
        }
    });
};
```

If the messege is below 160 character it is okey .Messege will be sent but if messege is above 160 character then it will throw new TypeError value argument is out of bounds in buffer.js if sms messege is too long.Please Help .will really appreciate any help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

solved this problem by this ..hope it helps someone someday

```
npm install gsm
The above module also splits the message into parts:

//We need to split the message and send it in many parts
var gsm = require('gsm');

var info = gsm("Your message string here");

//This is a unique id present in each message part
var concat_ref = this.concat_ref++; 

var part_id = 0;
info.parts.forEach(function(part) {
    part_id++;
    var udh = new Buffer(6);
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x5), 0); //Length of UDF
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x0), 1); //Indicator for concatenated message
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(0x3), 2); //  Subheader Length ( 3 bytes)
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(concat_ref), 3); //Same reference for all concatenated messages
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(info.sms_count), 4); //Number of total messages in the concatenation
    udh.write(String.fromCharCode(part_id), 5); //Sequence number ( used by the mobile to concatenate the split messages)

    var submit_pdu = {
        source_addr:msg.from,
        destination_addr: msg.to,
        short_message: { udh:udh, message:part },
        registered_delivery:1 //If you want a delivery report
    };

    this.getSession().submit_sm(submit_pdu, function(pdu) {
        if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
            console.log("SMPP Gateway[" + this.getOptions().address + "] - SUMBIT[" + submit_pdu.source_addr + ">>>" + submit_pdu.destination_addr + "] - " + pdu.message_id);
        }
        if(callback) {
            callback(pdu);
        }
    }.bind(this));
}.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `message_payload` parameter (field name) as stated in the official SMPP's [specification](https://smpp.org/SMPP_v3_4_Issue1_2.pdf) to send messages longer than 254 octets.

`message_payload` definition:

> Contains the extended short message user data. Up to 64K octets can be
> transmitted.

The official document says:

> Applications which need to send messages longer than 254 octets should
> use the message_payload parameter. In this case the sm_length field
> should be set to zero.
>
> The short message data should be inserted in either the short_message
> or message_payload fields. Both fields must not be used
> simultaneously.

I made a test with **node-smpp**, and it works. No need to concatenate.