# Is it possible to send bulk sms with node-smpp (https://github.com/farhadi/node-smpp)?

Tags: node.js, smpp

This is the code in the documentation

This is a complete implementation of SMPP v5.0 in node.js, with support for custom commands and TLVs.

SMPP v5.0, by design, is backward compatible with v3.4, so you would be able to use this module with 3.4 implementations. Even you can use this module with 3.3 implementations as far as you don't use TLV parameters and don't bind in transceiver mode.

The name of the methods and parameters in this implementation are equivalent to the names defined in SMPP specification. So get a copy of SMPP v5.0 Specification for a list of available operations and their parameters.

```js
var smpp = require('smpp');
var session = smpp.connect('smpp://example.com:2775');
session.bind_transceiver({
 system_id: 'YOUR_SYSTEM_ID',
 password: 'YOUR_PASSWORD'
}, function(pdu) {
 if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
  // Successfully bound
  session.submit_sm({
   destination_addr: 'DESTINATION NUMBER',
   short_message: 'Hello!'
  }, function(pdu) {
   if (pdu.command_status == 0) {
    // Message successfully sent
    console.log(pdu.message_id);
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48060832/how-to-send-long-message-using-node-smpp

Comment: i don't want split the message. i want to send it as bulk

Comment: @SayanMohsin  - Hi friend, did you successfully sending bulk SMS?.

Answer (score 0):

Generally sending advertisement SMS in bulk mode is done by using SMPP and as long as your ESME application is stable and scalable it is not important which SMPP API you use. You should have at least RX mode SMPP client connection to SMS Hub or MNO SMSC with TPS limit in order  to finish desired time frame. Your application should support parallel submission of SMPP packets with rate limiter which prevents receiving error response due to exceeding allowed TPS limit.